# Como navegar a un path diferente en el mismo dominio, incluyendo en el header un "athorization token"

Tags: javascript, html5, jwt, headers

Estoy montando una web que contiene dos páginas, la de "login" y la "principal".
En la ventana de login mando el user y el pass por Ajax, y espera un token jwt.

La idea es: una vez recibido el jwt en la página de login, navegar(desde javascript) a la página principal enviando en el header el jwt, pero no sé cómo hacerlo.
He visto que se puedo cambiar la URL mediante:

```
window.location.pathname = '/principal';
```

Pero no sé como incluir, ni si se puede, un header aquí.

Lo tengo mal solucionado mediante una petición XMLHttpRequest (que me permite incluir el header con el token), que una vez que me devuelve el contenido (HTML) se lo mando a la página mediante:

```
document.write(xmlHttp.responseText);
```

El problema que tiene esta solución es que no se actualiza la URL de navegación, y no se puede depurar desde el navegador (Chrome) por ser dinámico.

Tengo poca experiencia y no se si hay solución técnica, o lo habitual es un planteamiento diferente.

Muchas gracias de antemano por sus ideas.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Hace unos días tuve el mismo problema y se me ocurrieron 2 formas de solucionarlo, aunque ninguna es la ideal, ya que no son tan seguras como enviar el token como un header. Pero, visto que nadie ha contestado, te lo comento a ver si te sirve.

1. Podrías usar query string `window.location.href = '/principal?token=' + token`. En el backend deberías acceder al token con `req.query.token` en vez de `req.headers['token']` El problema es que quedaría el token visible en la url.
2. Podrías almacenar el token en una cookie. Pero deberías cambiar la lógica del backend, para almacenarlo `res.cookie('token', token,{ expires: new Date(Date.now() + (15*24*60*60*1000)) });` (en este ejemplo expira en 15 días). Para acceder a el `req.cookies.token`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. No es la solución que esperaba, pero son alternativas posibles. Probablemente deje login y contenido en la misma página y me evite este problema. En stackoverflow.com no he conseguido solución tampoco. Saludos